# How do I find the backlog parent of a task in TFS using ReST

Tags: rest, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have a backlog in TeamFoundationServer 2015, and I want to retrieve all the child tasks it links to using ReST and the WIQL. Is there a query to do this?

This is the current query I'm using, which is returning all my tasks, however, I do not see anything about the parent of the object being returned.

```
{"query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' && [System.TeamProject] = 'MyProject' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"}
```

Comment: Have you tried using? "?$expand=relations&api-version=1.0" at the end of your workItem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following query:

```html
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] From WorkItemLinks WHERE (Source.[System.TeamProject] = @project and Source.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item') and ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') and (Target.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') mode(Recursive)"
}
```